# NSUserDefault Value found nil with kill the App

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I just trying to save the user Id and status as true value in `UserDefaults` when they login or Register with App.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(user?.CustID, forKey: "CustID")
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "status")
```

so when the user reopen the app in my `Appdelegate` I check the Status if it's true then user directly pass on `HomeScreen` and if the status False its pass on login screen.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

         let status = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "status")

        if (status == true) && (custID != "") {
            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
            let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeTicketViewController") as! HomeTicketViewController
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: nextViewController)
            let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
        }else {
            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle:nil)
            let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: nextViewController)
            let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
        }
}
```

I get the status true but i found that The `CustID` found nil. 
Is there any solution for that?

Comment: I think you missed to write `synchronize()` after setting the value to `UserDefault`.

Comment: `synchronous()` Is what for?

Comment: no need for `synchronous`

Comment: What does the following line mean and where does custID come from?  if (status == true) && (custID != "") {}

Comment: @Kuldeep No. The documentation explains that `synchronize()` is not needed and could even cause issues. It will be deprecated in a future version of the SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `userdefault` if value not found in `userdefaults` corresponding to key then `userdefault` return `nil` and in case of bool it returns `false`.

In your case, when you app launches, app does not have any value corresponding to **custID** so you getting `nil`.

You need to add check like this

```
if (status == true) && (custID != nil){
    :
    :
}
```

Comment: which can be just `if status && custId != nil {...}`

Answer (score 1):

The default is false

```
 let status = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "status")
```

so status will be false at first , also status being true doesn't mean `CustID` saved no nil

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(user!.CustID, forKey: "CustID")
```

as user may be nil so force-unwrap to verify that